# Enable muti-select on Flow Layout in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, contextmenu, flowlayout

I'm using the example [Flow Layout from Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html) and I add multiple instances of a custom widget (named `Card`).

I want to enable the user to select one or more elements (Cards) in this layout and trigger a right-click menu. This menu will contain several actions which can be either performed on one or more of the Cards. That means, there also should be a way to get the selected items from the layout when an action is triggered.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Your help is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Use [eventFilter()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter)

Comment: That is to capture the context menu. But, how can I enable the flow layout to make the items selectable?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight : I'm asking for a design solution. So I think there is no point of posting a code snippet here, as everything you need is in that example. I'm simply instantiating that Flow Layout and adding my custom widgets to that.